# Filter Pandas Series and return values

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have the following series and I want to filter it down to between two values.  When I use between, boolean logic is return.  I want to filter the series to values between the two values and return those values.

```
# import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd
  
# Creating empty series
ser = pd.Series(range(1,10))

# between 3 and 7
ser = ser.between(3, 7)
```

This is what is returned:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
8    False
```

But what I am looking for is the following:

```
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
6    7
```

Comment: `ser[ser.between(3,7)]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
# import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd
  
# Creating empty series
ser = pd.Series(range(1,10))

# between 3 and 7
print(ser[ser.between(3, 7)])
```